# Images not displayed on gh-pages after deploying react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created an app, wherein i have given images paths as recommended by community. While running locally it loads and displays all the images but after i deployed on github pages, it is not taking the correct path to get the images. I dont know how to resolve the issue , can someone help me ?

i have tried adding %PUBLIC_URL% and all but nothing seems to work

This is what i have tried and works in local. My images are located under

```
public/images/login-background.png
```

```
 background: url('/images/login-background.jpg') center center
    no-repeat;
```

While i publish my project to github, url changes from 'localhost:3000' to 'https://singhkshitij.github.io/abc/' so all the images take url as

```
https://singhkshitij.github.io/images/login-background.png
```

while it should be

```
https://singhkshitij.github.io/abc/images/login-background.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you've used `create-react-app` to bootstrap your application. In which case you need to specify the `homepage` property in `package.json` to something like

```
  "homepage": "https://singhkshitij.github.io/abc",
```

Reference - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: I have already added the property and website is accessible just that images are not being fetched !

Comment: Quoting from the [CRA Website](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#when-to-use-the-public-folder) - "Normally we recommend importing stylesheets, images, and fonts from JavaScript". It would be nice to move the login-background.png alongside the css and refer it as `./login-background.png` and import that CSS into the Login React Component. That way webpack would setup the paths correctly for the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Basically you need to change

```
 url('/images/login-background.jpg')
```

to

```
url('homepagePath/images/login-background/jpg')
```

where `homepagePath` is the url of your application served by github:
`https://{username}.github.io/{reponame}`

Comment: This does not look as the right solution for me, as when running your project locally you'd need to also refer to the external repository